# How would you solve this geometry problem analytically?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I encountered the following problem:
The point K is interior to the parallelogram ABCD and is such that the midpoint M of the side
BC is equidistant from points K and D, and the midpoint N of side CD is equidistant from
points K and B. Point P is the midpoint of segment AK. Prove that $\angle{PBK} =\angle{PDK}$

This problem is approachable with synthetic geometry but personally I think that this solution is quite "ugly" and "unnatural" which is why I wanted to resolve this problem with more of a analytic approach

My first attempt was to use polar coordinates, yet I remained uncertain of how to express the equidistant condition. Thus, I found myself in need of assistance and humbly sought guidance. May I be so fortunate as to find the answer I'm searching for.

For the synthetic sol:
Through the vertex C of the parallelogram we build
a line parallel to the diagonal BD, intersecting
AB and AD at points $B_1$ respectively
and $D_1$. This creates two new parallelograms and further reasoning solves the problem.

Diagram:
[image: Diagram 1]

Comment: A figure would help readers follow the description.

Comment: A diagram would help here.

Comment: Adding a diagram sorry

Comment: If you have a solution using synthetic geometry, then you should include at least an outline of it in your question. This may give others a jumping-off point for an analytic proof without having to duplicate your effort. Also, explaining what exactly you find "ugly" and "unnatural" about the solution may help others provide solutions you'll find satisfactory.

Comment: @Blue I will add It. I just didn't have the patience

Comment: is |AD| = |AB| and |CB|=|CD| ?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct the blue circle with N as center and radius = NB = NK.

[image]

Draw NS perpendicular to BK cutting BK at S. Then S is the midpoint of BK. Applying ‘midpoint theorem’ to $\triangle KAB$, we get PS || and = 0.5 AB = 0.5DC = DN. That means DNSP is a ||gm. Similarly, BMTP is also a ||gm.

Hence, $\angle BRK= \angle KTM = 90^0$. Similarly, $\angle DUK = \angle KSN = 90^0$.

Result follows from the fact that RBDU is cyclic.

Comment: That is a much cleaner solution than mine. But I am still looking for an analytical approach rather than a synthetic one. Great tho thanks for submitting!<3